# How to create multiple sendkeys macro linear order of operations

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros

```
Range ("D5").Select
ActiveCell.Resize(1, 25).Select
SendKeys ("%y1"), True 'Alt+Y1
SendKeys ("%y2"), True 'Alt+Y2, Activates third part add-in
SendKeys ("~"), True 'Enter, initiates the merge add-in function

Range ("D6").Select
ActiveCell.Resize(1, 25).Select
SendKeys ("%y1"), True 'Alt+Y1
SendKeys ("%y2"), True 'Alt+Y2, Activates third part add-in
SendKeys ("~"), True 'Enter, initiates the merge add-in function
```

Continued to select each Cell in Column D until D40...

Every time I run the SendKeys code VBA only initiates the last command in the sequence. I try using wait or sleep, but the macro just delays the listed time-frame and then only runs the last set of operations. I need this to run in a linear fashion (in order of desired operations).

How do I make sure the set of keystrokes happen linearly and in sequence?

Answer (score 1):

Use `DoEvents`

```
Range ("D5").Select
ActiveCell.Resize(1, 25).Select
DoEvents
SendKeys ("%y1"), True 'Alt+Y1
DoEvents
SendKeys ("%y2"), True 'Alt+Y2, Activates third part add-in
DoEvents
SendKeys ("~"), True 'Enter, initiates the merge add-in function
DoEvents

Range ("D6").Select
ActiveCell.Resize(1, 25).Select
DoEvents
SendKeys ("%y1"), True 'Alt+Y1
DoEvents
SendKeys ("%y2"), True 'Alt+Y2, Activates third part add-in
DoEvents
SendKeys ("~"), True 'Enter, 
DoEvents
```

Comment: If I only add DoEvents at the bottom of each set of SendKeys it works better because the operating system doesn't have to stop after each command. This allows me to use the Excel keystroke shortcuts to initiate a 3rd Party Excel Add-in. Thank you for your help! This solved my problem.